# Class scope and private members?

Tags: c++, class, scope, non-member-functions

I am defining a function to add elements to the `vector<Point> original_points`, named 
 `void add_point()`. Why is highlighting **`original_points`** as *undefined*, in the function body, when I am using *type qualifier: friend* (to gain access) and it is *in the scope of the class*?

```
// data structure representing Point in 2D plane
class Point{
public:
  //contructors
  Point();
  Point(double x, double y);
  // non-modifying methods
  inline double get_xcoord()const{return xcoord;}
  inline double get_ycoord()const{return ycoord;}
  // modifying methods
  inline double set_xcoord(double x){xcoord=x;}
  inline double set_ycoord(double y){ycoord=y;}
  // non-member function with access to private members
  friend inline void add_point(const Point& p){original_points.push_back();}
private:
  double xcoord;
  double ycoord;
  vector<Point> original_points;};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `p.original_points`. A friend function is not a member function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `p.original_points.push_back` wouldn't work. `p` is a `const` reference.

Comment: Where is the `vector<string>`?

Comment: Off topic, but `friend` functions defined inside the class are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: Thank you all guys! What's with the down voting, is the question not formulated right, the title, the tags? Or is it a too stupid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friend is a non-member function, so it can't access non-static members directly; it would need a `Point` object to act on. You also need to pass something to `push_back`.

It's unclear whether the function parameter `p` should be the object to access, the object to pass to `push_back`, or both; or whether this should actually be a member, not a friend. The latter seems more likely - you probably want:

```
void add_point(const Point& p){original_points.push_back(p);}
```

Answer (score 3):

There at least three major problems:

**First**, `std::vector::push_back()` has a parameter. You need to pass a `Point` instance to it. It seems you want to add `p`:

```
original_points.push_back(p);
```

**Second**, A friend function is a non-member, so you cannot access members of a class through it without an instance of that class. You don't have such an instance, so your friend function makes no sense. This would compile, but would have no effect:

```
friend 
inline void add_point(const Point& p){
  Point x;
  x.original_points.push_back(p);
}
```

Perhaps you wanted `add_point()` to be a member, in which case it shouldn't be a `friend`. That would fix the second problem, ***but***...

**Third**, assuming `original_points` is an `std::vector<Point>`, such containers cannot be instantiated with an incomplete type. So `Point` cannot have a data member `std::vector<Point>` without invoking *undefined behaviour*. If on the other hand, it were a `boost::container::<Point>`, or another `vector` that supports incomplete types, that would be fine.

All in all, your code seems quite broken.

Comment: `object_inst.original_points.push_back(object_inst);` is what I wanted to avoid. It seems that, it would be better if I exclude the `vector` form the class together with the `add_point()` function.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis If `original_points` is a data member of a class, you need to access it via an object of that class, it can't exist on its own. In any case, the vector can't be part of the class (see third point above.)

Answer (score 1):

Friends do get access to the non-public parts of a class. But that's not the issue here—the function is still a non-member (if it were a member, it wouldn't have to be a friend). The function needs an *object* to access that object's non-static members. What you've got is basically the same as this:

```
class Point
{
public:
  vector<Point> original_points;
};

void add_point(const Point &p) { original_points.push_back(p); }
```

There is no `original_points` for `add_point` to refer to.

Either you wanted `original_points` to be `static`, or you'll have to pass a `Point` object into `add_point` to access its `original_points` member, or access it on `p`.

As a side note, `push_back()` takes one argument—you must specify *what* to add to the vector (but I assume that was supposed to be `p`).

Answer (score 0):

As you say you want to add Point type element to the vector which keeps string type elements, so you may have type mismatch error also. But for undefined, I had the same error and it turned out that it was caused by string type, when you are using string you should mention that you are using string from standard library, so I added "using namespace std;" and the error went. 
It may help you also.

Comment: Wut please? And don't recommend `using namespace std;`, never!

Comment: I didn't recommend, I said what may be the reason.

Comment: _" I said what may be the reason."_ It isn't the reason.

Comment: I didn't say, it is, I said it may be.

Comment: Leave such speculations as comments (I know you can't yet), but not as answers please!

Answer (score 0):

The thought behind putting `vector<Point>` and `add_point(const Point& p)` inside a class was to ensure some locality. To put then under common `namespace` should be a better solution(?)

```
namespace MyPoint{
// data structure representing Point in 2D plane
class Point{
public:
//contructors
Point();
Point(double x, double y);
// non-modifying methods
inline double get_xcoord()const{return xcoord;}
inline double get_ycoord()const{return ycoord;}
// modifying methods
inline double set_xcoord(double x){xcoord=x;}
inline double set_ycoord(double y){ycoord=y;}


private:
double xcoord;
double ycoord;};
vector<Point> original_points;
void add_point(const Point& p){original_points.push_back(p);} //end of namespace
```